# Twitter API: GET followers/ids method always returns "rate limit reached'

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitter4j, sttwitterapi

I'm using Tweepy (latest version, python 3.6) to get a twitter account's followers' ids:

```
myids = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=account_screen_name).items()
```

This always returns a "rate limit reached" error. I then check my remaining number of requests as well as the reset time with:

```
api.rate_limit_status()['resources']['followers']
```

This gives '0' for the number of remaining requests, and '1536311215' for the reset time. Still, even after waiting for more than one day, without running any script, thoses values do not refresh... May this be related to the recent changes of the Twitter API?

Comment: Which version of Twitter4J are you using in your project (exactly) ?

Comment: As stated, I'm using tweepy. The issue vanished by itself...maybe was server-related.